# Find the limit as n approaches infinite

Tags: limits

We have the following function:

$$U_n = \sin \dfrac{1}{3} n \pi$$

What is the limit of this function as n approaches infinity?

I first tried to use my calculator as help, for n I chose some arbitrary large numbers, such as 100 and 1000. Then I I just took $n = 10^{50}$ and it gave me an error.

So the correct answer is it doesn't have one, but why? Why does this function have a solution for $n = 10^2, 10^3$ and not for bigger numbers such as $n=10^{50}$?

Comment: Don't trust your calculator too much - you're right that it doesn't have one, but it doesn't do anything interesting at $n = 10^{50}$ which it doesn't do for smaller $n$.  The calculator just isn't good with large numbers like that.

Comment: Your calculator cannot handle such large numbers. This does not mean, e.g., that  $U_{10^{50}}$ is undefined.  However, you should be able to evaluate $U_n$ exactly without a calculator; $n\pi/3$ is a "special angle" for each $n$. The sequence of angles, in degree measure, is $60^\circ$, $120^\circ$, $180^\circ$, $240^\circ$, $300^\circ$, $360^\circ$, ... (note the pattern then repeats).

Comment: It gave you an error, because 10^50 is two big a number too fit in your calculator's operational memory - not because the function is undefined at n=10^50. Also: 10^50 (or even 10^500000000000000000000000000000000!) is a VERY **small** number compared to infinity - knowing the value of a function for some "large" number x doesn't help you AT ALL with finding it's limit at infinity.

Comment: @VladK. It has helped me very often, so I absolutely disagree. Also, every real number is small compared to infinity, I know that. That's not why I did it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David hinted in his comment, try using the fact that
$$
\sin(x + 2\pi k) = \sin(x)
$$
whenever $k$ is an integer.  Or, if you just write out the first few values of $U_n$ (compute these using the [unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle)) and you should notice a pattern.